# C# inheritance and exceptions text

Tags: c#, exception, inheritance

Good day!

I create two classes:

```
class A
{
  public A(String name) {}
  public void Func1()
  {
      try 
      {...}
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLIne("Error at Func1 of class A"+Ex.Message);
      }
  }
}

class B:A
{
   public B()  {}
}
```

at Main():

```
B b=new B(String name);
b.Func1();
```

And when Exception comes- a get errror like this: "Error at class A Func1"!
So, it confuse me.

How a can fix it?  Should i override each function of class A and do like that:

```
void override Func1()
{
  try {
    _a.Fun1();
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {//My text of exception}
}
```

or impement interface?
Please , tell me!

Thanks!

Comment: The Exceptions _stack trace_ already gives you this information. Are you sure you want to be putting this text in your exception? The Exception message usually shows the suspected cause of the exception - you must have known what went wrong in order to throw it!

Comment: Sounds like whatever is happening in the try is throwing an exception which is unrelated to the structure you have provided.

Comment: @Gusdor One problem, however, is that you'll get the method name with the class where the method is defined. So the stack trace will show `A.Func1` instead of `B.Func1`. While understandable and overall a good idea, the OP seems to want the actual type that's running (which most likely means his inheritance tree is pretty weird :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding is one option, but it's pretty weird.

Instead, you can use `this.GetType()` to get the name of the type you're actually in:

```
Console.WriteLine("Error at class " + GetType().Name + ": " + Ex.Message);
```

However, this is a bit weird pattern of exception handling. For one, the information you're printing out is in the stack trace of the exception, no need to manually write the name of the method etc. True, it's a bit verbose, but that's usually quite useful.

Of course, if you still want to follow this pattern, you don't have to write the name of the method manually:

```
"Method " + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + ", class " + GetType().Name
```

The point here is that your `B` type has no method `Func1` - it only does a virtual dispatch to `A`'s method `Func1`, with a reference to itself. Since `GetType()` gets you the actual type of a given instance (in this case, `this`), you get what you want even in classes that inherit from your base class.

Overriding all the methods in all the classes and replacing their whole code would kind of completely defeat the purpose of inheritance, wouldn't it?

Comment: @user2545071 Well, the basic idea here is to ask yourself who benefits from the message. Is it for the user of your application? He gets nothing from knowing the name of the method and class where this happened. Is it for you? You probably want the complete stack trace, which also shows you the line where the error occured, along with the caller tree. Another important thing is to ask yourself whether you're handling the exception in the right place. Does it really make sense to handle it in that method, or should it be propagated higher? Perhaps you only want `try ... finally` to cleanup?